# I'm facing an issue to find if this textarea value is iframe or simple text. Can someone help me?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, iframe

I'm facing an issue to find if this textarea value is iframe or a simple text. Here if the textarea value is equal to iframe then i need put the embeded iframe into `<div class="widgetVideoEdit">`. Can someone help me?

HTML:

```
<div class="widgetVideoEdit widgetWrap" style="display: block;"><div class="videoEmbededCode"><textarea class="embededCode" placeholder="Paste here video embeded code"></textarea><button type="button" class="LPbtn-primary LPbtn-lg">insert</button></div><div class="LPtempEditArea"><i class="fa fa-clone LPclone"></i><i class="fa fa-arrows LPdraggable"></i><i class="fa fa-trash LPremove"></i></div><div class="videoPlaceholder"><i class="fa fa-play-circle"></i></div></div>
```

JQuery:

```
$(document).on('click', '.LPbtn-primary', function(){
            var embededCode = $(this).parent('.videoEmbededCode').children('.embededCode');
            var alertText = $('<p class="alertText">').text('Please add code').prependTo($(this).parent('.videoEmbededCode'));
            var videoContent = $(embededCode).val();
            //alert(videoContent);
            if($(videoContent) ===''){
                console.log('please add code');
                $(alertText);
                }
                else {

                    $('.widgetVideoEdit').html(videoContent);

                    }

        });
```

Check it here: https://jsfiddle.net/Issact/0ueefc1p/3/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add some basic check for the value of the textarea for keywords like `<iframe` etc.

This would look like so:

```
if (videoContent.indexOf("<iframe") >= 0){
  alert("The text in textarea contains the string <iframe");
} else {
  alert("There does not seem to be an iframe in the textarea text.");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution of your javascript could be like this

```
$(document).on('click', '.LPbtn-primary', function(){
  var embededCode = $(this).parent('.videoEmbededCode').children('.embededCode');
  var videoContent = $(embededCode).val();

  if($(videoContent) ===''){
    $('<p class="alertText">').text('Please add code').prependTo($(this).parent('.videoEmbededCode'));
  } else {
    $('.widgetVideoEdit').html(videoContent);
  }
});
```